# number of solutions of $\frac{dy}{dx}$+ |y|=0,

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the number of solutions of $\frac{dy}{dx}$+ |y|=0, y (0)=1

1. 0
2. 1
3. 2
4. More than 2

I need to solve this question. Plz give suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

proceed buy taking two cases of $y$ and $-y$ converting into two very simple differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+|y|=0$$
now for $y>0$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$
thus $$\log cy=-x$$
$$y=\frac{e^{-x}}{c}$$
thus as $y(0)=1$ $c=1$ 
now $y$ cannot be negative over all domain , so we check the case so as to form composite functions .
similarly you can solve for $y<0$

Comment: Where to use y (0)=1?

Comment: on integrating you will get a constant term , which will be evaluated using that.

Comment: I know, but we have case for y $\gt $0 and y $ \lt $0, in which case to use this initial value. If used in one of them, what about constant in other case?

Comment: yes that you have , so the options are like that , so you can have more than one equation possible.